# Ho to do this using Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex code that matches the folowing pattern :

```
{format:Tx.(string_of_date_format)}
```

where Tx can be T-n T-1 T0 T1 T2 Tn
and string_of_date_format could be any string that represents a date format yyyyMMdd as example
this is my implementation which I couldn't figure out why it didn't match

```
{format:^T(-?[0-9]+)([+-][0-9]+)?$[.]([a-zA-Z])}
```

so I can use it like in this example: `{format:T2.(yyyyMMdd)}`

Comment: So would `T-0` be allowed? You specifically started out with `T-1` and the positive integers with `T0`. Is that on purpose? Also, do you have sample data where you would need your optional group?

Comment: it would be better if it start the positive values with T instead of T-0

Comment: So to recap: `T-0` and `T0` are both not allowed? which would boil down to no leading zero's in the integer part? Or am I misunderstanding you here?

Comment: T represents Today, so it would be better that T0 or T-0 be just T

Comment: Right, and can you explain the use of your optional capture group `([+-][0-9]+)` with some sample data that would make sense of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
{format:T-?[0-9]+(?:[+-][0-9]+)?\.\([a-zA-Z]+\)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3IJRkW/2). Details:

- `{format:T` - a literal string
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[+-][0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of `+` or `-` and then one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `\)}` - `)}` substring.